# How can I buttons with ForEach that changes the background?

Tags: javascript

I want to create 4 buttons with JS that changes the background of the container using only ForEach.
I have the 4 buttons ready using foreach but the colors of the background don't change.
any help?
here's my code:

```
let color_ar = ["yellow", "green", "blue", "silver"];
let buttons_ar = ["btn btn-warning", "btn btn-success", "btn btn-primary", "btn btn-secondary"];
window.onload = function() {
    createBtn();
}

function createBtn() {
    buttons_ar.forEach(function(item, i) {
        document.querySelector("#id_container").innerHTML += `<button id="id_button" class="${item}">${color_ar[i]}</button>`
        document.querySelector("#id_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
            i = 0;
            document.querySelector("#id_container").style.background = color_ar[i++];
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: don't use "id_button" as it is getting repeated more than 1. the id is not meant to get repeated more than one your query selector identifies only the first id_button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `id_button` for the click, which only work on the 1st item, because ID's are unique.

Here's a way to do what you want

```js
const color_ar = ["yellow", "green", "blue", "silver"],
  buttons_ar = ["btn btn-warning", "btn btn-success", "btn btn-primary", "btn btn-secondary"];

function createBtn() {
  buttons_ar.forEach((item, i) => {
    document.querySelector("#id_container").innerHTML += `<button id="id_button" class="${item}">${color_ar[i]}</button>`
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.background = e.currentTarget.textContent))
  })
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  createBtn();
})
```

```html
<div id='id_container'></div>
```